# Sharepoint Camlex Caml Join error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2010, caml, csom

Hi I'm new to the world of sharepoint and caml, so any hints to point me in the right direction helpful.

I've picked up the Camlex https://camlex.codeplex.com/ library to help me make caml queries in a nice way.

All was working well, until I added in a InnerJoin

```
var caml =
                Camlex.Query().
                InnerJoin(x => x[CesaDocument.DocType_field].PrimaryList(CESAContext.Documents).ForeignList(CESAContext.DocumentType)).
                Where(x => (string)x[CesaDocument.RiOID_field] == id).
                Scope(ViewScope.RecursiveAll).ToCamlQuery();
```

At first the code came out with the Join at the end - believing that was the problem I got the source code and I managed to get the Join at the start.

So that gave me this code.

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
 <Joins>    <Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="Document Types">    
 <Eq>        <FieldRef List="Documents" Name="Doc_x0020_Type" RefType="Id" />       
 <FieldRef List="Document Types" Name="Id" />      
 </Eq>    </Join>  </Joins> <Query> <Where>     <Eq>
 <FieldRef Name="RiO_x0020_ID" />
 <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
 </Eq>    </Where>  </Query></View>
```

However that still errored -giving me this code.

```
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

When I called the execute function.

```
List list = null;
            ListItemCollection ListCollection = null;

            list = this.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(List);

            ListCollection = list.GetItems(query);


            this.Load(ListCollection);
            this.ExecuteQuery();

return ListCollection;
```

Googling seems to bring up to turn `allowunsafeUpdates=true` but I'm using the Micrsoft.Sharepoint.Client object and I can't see that property nor am I updating.
I've pasted the Caml query into SP CAML Query Helper Online and it runs as expected.

Am I doing this right? 
I've tried a few ways but to no avail. 
Should I be using the SPQuery object, can that work with CSOM - if so what library is that in.

Should I be using `Document_x0020_Types` in my join?
Edit - tried that but didn't work.

Edit2
Just thought this would work but no.

```
<Joins>
  <Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="Document_x0020_Types">
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef List="Documents" Name="Doc_x0020_Type" RefType="Id" />
      <FieldRef List="Document_x0020_Types" Name="Id" />
    </Eq>
  </Join>
</Joins>
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="RiO_x0020_ID" />
        <Value Type="Text">2</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

Edit 3
So now I knew a little more about the format of Caml I could fix my camlex generater.

```
var caml =
                Camlex.Query()
                .InnerJoin(x => x[CesaDocument.DocType_field].ForeignList(CESAContext.DocumentType))
                .Where(x => (string)x[CesaDocument.RiOID_field] == id)
                .Scope(ViewScope.RecursiveAll)
                .ToCamlQuery();
```

Just dropping the primary bit did the trick!

Comment: Is RiOID a field on your Documents list or on your Document Types list?

Comment: RiOID is in the 'Documents' list. It's not in the types list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is what the builder generated for you...

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Joins>
        <Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="Document Types">
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef List="Documents" Name="Doc_x0020_Type" RefType="Id" />
                <FieldRef List="Document Types" Name="Id" />
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="RiO_x0020_ID" />
                <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Problem:** You shouldn't need the attribute `List="Documents"` in the first `<FieldRef>` element of your join.

**Explanation:** The `List` attribute is supposed to only take an alias which is defined in a preceding `ListAlias` attribute of a `Join` element. The primary list in a join only needs a `List` attribute if you are joining additional lists off a foreign list, in which case the alias would be defined by a preceding join. If the `List` attribute is omitted, the primary list of the join will be the list against which the query is being executed.

The generated CAML query above is otherwise valid if your lists take the following shape:

1. The list that you are querying with this CAML (and which I'm guessing is named Documents) has a lookup field with an internal name of `Doc_x0020_Type`.
2. That same Documents list has a text field with an internal name of `RiO_x0020_ID`

If either of those are false (such as if your `RiO_x0020_ID` field is actually on the `Document Types` list, not on `Documents`), then the query will fail. Note that you **don't** need to specify the actual name of the foreign list to which you're joining, since the mapping parallels an existing lookup field relation.

**Further reading:** For more information on how to use Joins in CAML (and the related concept of Projections/Projected Fields, which is necessary if you want to do any filtering based on the values in the joined foreign list) you can refer to Microsoft's documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help, yeah removing that List="Documents" did the trick. I guess I need to look at the Camlex library and my use of it. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah fixed my camlex (now I knew what I was doing!)